# Adding select options to a dynamically generated form using knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

How would I go about replacing one of the dynamically generated input fields with a dropdown box.
ie. I want to replace the first input field with a dropdown.

```
<select><option value='1'>1</option><option = '2'>2</option></select>
```

Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/z9tWd/

Answer (score 0):

You want to use templating. Something like

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: template, data: $data }"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WYH68/

There are also libraries that help you make these neater, like this one (Im the author) 
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.BindingConventions

Same example as above would look like
http://jsfiddle.net/C2Gky/

Comment: Added observables to last example so that you can see the effect in real time http://jsfiddle.net/C2Gky/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `if` binding to chose between `input` and `select`:

```
<!-- ko if: type() === 'input' -->
<input data-bind="value: name" />
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: type() === 'select' -->
<select data-bind="options: options,optionsCaption: 'Choose...', value: name">
</select>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Then you can change your `Item` like this:

```
function Item(id, options) {
    this.id = ko.observable(id);
    this.type = ko.observable(options instanceof Array ? "select" : "input");
    this.name = ko.observable(this.type() === 'input' ? options : undefined);
    this.options = ko.observableArray(this.type() === 'select' ? options : null);
    this.dirtyFlag = new ko.dirtyFlag(this);
}
```

When you create an `Item`, if you pass it an Array as the second parameter, a drop down list will automatically be created:

```
this.items = ko.observableArray([
    new Item(1, "one"),
    new Item(2, "two"),
    new Item(3, "three"),
    new Item(4, ["1", "2"])
]);
```

Note that your `isDirty` still works.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GabrielTran/z9tWd/1/)